# Is the Dihedral Group $D_5$ solvable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

I just showed that $D_4$ is solvable since it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 x \mathbb{Z}_2$ so since $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is solvable so is $D_4$.  Does something similar extend to $D_5$ or is there a better way of showing both?

Comment: It's not exactly relevant, but there appears to be a notation clash if $D_4$ refers to a group with $4$ elements; $D_5$ could only possibly refer to a group with $10$ elements.

Comment: @pjs36 D4 has 8 elements

Comment: What is the meaning of $\mathbb{Z}_2 x \mathbb{Z}_2$ here? Direct product of two copies of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ ? But this would have only $4$ elements...

Answer (score 3):

All dihedral groups $D_n$ have an abelian normal subgroup order $n$ (in fact it is cyclic) with the corrresponding quotient abelian (of order 2, to be precise) and so they are solvable.